# Intuition of a k-connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, intuition

The formal definition of a k-connected graph $G$ is:

> $\nexists x\subseteq V(G)$ with $|x| \le k - 1$ such that $G-x$ is
>   disconnected.

What is the intuition behind this? What does it mean to be 2-connected or 3-connected?

Comment: A $1$-connected graph is just a connected graph. But you might be interested in how connected it is: for instance, is there an edge you can remove to make it disconnected? If not, it's not just connected, it's $2$-connected. And so forth. Is there a specific kind of intuition you're looking for?

Comment: I'm just trying to gain an intuition for what higher connectedness really means. I guess that makes sense - the more connected it is, the more edges you need to remove.

Comment: To rephrase what you wrote in words - A graph is $k$-connected if whenever you remove any set of $k-1$ vertices of $G$ the graph remains connected. Hence in order to make $G$ disconnected you must remove at least $k$ vertices and thus $k$ gives a measure of connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much connected a graph is? k-connectedness is a measure of connectedness of a graph. Suppose you have a connected graph. Deleting vertices from the graph results deleting its incident edges also. For a given graph $G$, suppose minimum number of vertices you should remove to make its disconnected is $k$. Then, the graph is $k$-connected. Some examples will make it more transparent.

Draw a circle of 5 vertices. Remove one vertex. Is the resultant graph disconnected? To make it disconnected minimum two vertices to be removed. Every circle is 2-connected.

Draw a complete graph. How many vertices do you need to make it disconnected? Measure its connectivity!